# How to simulate target="_blank" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When a user clicks on a link, I need to update a field in a database and then open the requested link in a new window.  The update is no problem, but I don't know how to open a new window without requiring them to click on another hyperlink.

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('redirect').click">
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com?ReportID=1" id="redirect" target="_blank">Report</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hm? `target="_top"` does not open in a new window - `target="_blank"` does.

Comment: If the link is already opening in a new window (due to target="_blank") and the javascript click handler is already updating your database, why would you need to open the new window with Javascript at all?

Answer (score 387, accepted):

```
<script>
    window.open('http://www.example.com?ReportID=1', '_blank');
</script>
```

The second parameter is optional and is the name of the target window.

Comment: `window.open` does what `target="_blank"` does - it opens the URL in a new window.

Comment: yes.  the second argument to window.open() is the "name" you want to give the window, similar to setting a target on a link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:window.open

Comment: Oh, I see.  window.open is blocked by Firefox pop-up blocker, but target="_blank" isn't.
Should I just ask the client to enable popups from their own website?

Comment: Is there a JavaScript solution that does not get blocked by pop-up blockers like that of Firefox?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale blocking window.open is kinda the point of pop-up blockers!  If you make the call in response to a click action it has a better chance of not being blocked.

Comment: remenber to add rel="noopener noreferrer" in order to avoid security leaks

Answer (score 26):

This might help

```
var link = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
    link.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    link.target = '_blank';
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': false,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    link.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: IE11: "Runtime Javascript error: not a valid action for the object"

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding some description of what is happening

Comment: @EllyPost it creates a link programmatically, then creates an event - same event browser creates when a user clicks on a screen. It basically simulates user input programmatically. As a side note, in this case "trusted" property of the event will be set to "false" as opposite to the real user generated events

Answer (score 19):

I know this is a done and sorted out deal, but here's what I'm using to solve the problem in my app.

```
if (!e.target.hasAttribute("target")) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    e.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    e.target.click();
    return;
}
```

Basically what is going on here is I run a check for if the link has `target=_blank` attribute. If it doesn't, it stops the link from triggering, sets it up to open in a new window then programmatically clicks on it.

You can go one step further and skip the stopping of the original click (and make your code a whole lot more compact) by trying this:

```
if (!e.target.hasAttribute("target")) {
    e.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
}
```

If you were using jQuery to abstract away the implementation of adding an attribute cross-browser, you should use this instead of `e.target.setAttribute("target", "_blank")`:

```
    jQuery(event.target).attr("target", "_blank")
```

You may need to rework it to fit your exact use-case, but here's how I scratched my own itch.

**Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLZq8/2/) of it in action for you to mess with.**

*(The link in jsfiddle comes back to this discussion .. no need a new tab :))*

Comment: I prefer this answer over all because, well, it uses jquery, and it avoids the window.open popup blocker issues. This is perfectly legitimate when dealing with some 3rd party data that contains links which are missing the target.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I do it with jQuery. I have a class for each link that I want to be opened in new window.

```
$(function(){

    $(".external").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open(this.href);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer using the following code if it is for a single link. Otherwise it's probably best if you create a function with similar code.

```
onclick="this.target='_blank';"
```

I started using that to bypass the W3C's XHTML strict test.

Comment: I think inline JavaScript is more messy than adding a "non-standard" attribute that works everywhere.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen in certain situations it is the only solution

Comment: @Claudiu: If you find yourself in such an absurd situation you should rather fix the cause than kludge around it.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the href from the a tag:

```
window.open(document.getElementById('redirect').href);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it on my website. Severa buttons call one javascript function, which always opens a new tab for each new web page.

```
<button type="button" onclick="newTab('http://google.com')">search</button>
<button type="button" onclick="newTab('http://amazon.com')">buy</button>
<button type="button" onclick="newTab('http://gmail.com')">read</button>
<script>
    function newTab(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't use `button` for links. [More info](https://www.tempertemper.net/blog/if-you-need-a-link-dont-use-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to **open all page links**:

```
$(".myClass").each(
     function(i,e){
        window.open(e, '_blank');
     }
);
```

It will open every `<a href="" class="myClass"></a>` link items to another tab like you would had clicked each one.

*You only need to paste it to browser console.* jQuery framework required

Answer (score 0):

When the person is holding **shift down** and you programmatically want to open a new tab (not a new window) the solution is to wrap a **timeout** around it.

It depends on your browsers settings but default Chrome behaviour has a problem with "shift down + javascript's window.open()" combination.

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        // Shift down + window.open() requires a "timeout" wrapper
        // Else a "new window" opens instead of a new tab
        setTimeout(() => window.open(url, '_blank'))
    } else {
        // if shift is not down this will open a new tab
        window.open(url, '_blank')
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

changes in js
(href='#' target='_blank')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).