# How to open image links in new window with window.location

Tags: wordpress, window.location

I have added following code in wordpress to hide status bar. It works but I want to open link in new window. How can I do that?

```
<img style='cursor:pointer;' src='http://www.killerpreseller.com/images2/buynow.gif' onclick="window.location='http://www.yahoo.com'"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
window.open('http://www.killerpreseller.com/images2/buynow.gif', '_blank');
```

As per [How to simulate target="_blank" in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574008/how-to-simulate-target-blank-in-javascript)

This is the equivalent of an anchor tag with target='blank' set.

Answer (score 1):

Use an anchor with target [`'_blank'`](http://www.createafreewebsite.net/anchor_tag_image.html) wrapping your image

```
<a href='http://www.killerpreseller.com/images2/buynow.gif' target='_blank'>
   <img style='cursor:pointer;' src='http://www.killerpreseller.com/images2/buynow.gif' />
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ree5t/