# How to get my Javascript form to open in a new window upon submission

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

Right now it only opens in the same window, I want it to open in a new window upon submisson.

**Here's what's in the head:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getURL(val){ 
base = 'http://www.domain.com/'; 
location = base + val; 
return false; 
} 
</script>
```

**Here's the what's in the body:**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return getURL(this.url.value)"> 
<label> 
<input type="text" name="url" /> 
</label> 
<label> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
</label> 
</form>
```

Comment: um, window.open() or just set the target and action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a new window on form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/896724/how-to-open-a-new-window-on-form-submit)

Comment: please search through previous answered questions before asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574008/how-to-simulate-target-blank-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
<form target="_blank" ...></form>
```

Further reading:

[When to use target = _blank](http://css-tricks.com/use-target_blank/)

Comment: Not going to work....It will submit the form to a new window, but not take them to the location they are after.

Comment: Why? It is in the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp): "_Display the response received in a new window or tab_".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in javascript, but it may get blocked by a popup blocker.

```
window.open(location);
```